# Use native Windows 10/11 methods to mute/unmute the system

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, powershell

So I want to enable or disable the audio on Windows 10/11 but not toggle it. After doing some research I found a method in PowerShell as the following:

```bsh
$obj = new-object -com wscript.shell 
$obj.SendKeys([char]173)
```

The problem is that it can only be used in order to toggle the audio. I'm trying to make so if your audio is enabled then the code will run but nothing will happen unless it's disabled .

Edit: I want to do so with minimal commands and without using external tools

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255419/how-can-i-mute-unmute-my-sound-from-powershell and 
https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets

Comment: @Gantendo That's great but like I specified I want to only use native Windows methods so no external tools!

Comment: Have you read the first link I posted?